# How many hours do you devote to answering questions on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

People who have 50k+ reputation: how many hours do you spend answering questions on Stack Overflow and how long did it take you to pass the 50k mark.

Comment: I did not read the entire question, so please ignore my answer. I do not have 50K rep.

Comment: If I have 5k should I take the hours I devote to answering questions and multiply by ten?

Comment: for people of 50k+ I would ask them how many hours does your day have?! :)

Comment: @sebastian pretty neat lol!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the data dump provides enough information to see when someone hit 50k, but you can see the [average reputation gain per day for 50k users](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/12316/?MinReputation=50000) to see how high it is. They don't seem to be incredibly high except for the top users, most of them have just been SO members for 500+ days

Comment: I now see that I average 5 Reputation/Day. Do you think 200 Reputation/Day is humanly possible?

Answer (score 2):

It took [me](https://stackoverflow.com/users/222908/daniel-vassallo) 10 months minus a few of days to reach 50k on SO, which I happen to [have hit just a couple of days ago](http://twitter.com/#!/DVassallo/status/26406567515).

I don't actually dedicate time to answer questions. I leave the site open on my secondary monitor when I'm using only the main one, and when I see something interesting I pop in to contribute<sup>1</sup>. Nevertheless, I can easily estimate that this takes away about 2 hours of productivity every day, but if I consider what I have learnt and how answering questions helped me sharpen my skills, I believe I had that time returned back with interest.

---

<sup>1</sup> In addition, I have recently been using the [StackGuru](https://stackapps.com/questions/345/stackguru-a-jabber-bot-for-all-stackapps-sites) bot to get a notification on gtalk whenever a question is posted on a tag that I follow. This app is great!